# Non-overlapping constraint on Django postgres IntegerRangeField

Tags: django, postgresql

Django has support for Postgres' range [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#range-fields).

In Postgres, we can have a non-overlapping constraint ("exclusion constraint") as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rangetypes.html) at section 8.17.10.

How can I apply this constraint in Django on the Field itself?

I am using django 1.8 and postgres 9.4.

An example from the docs of creating a table with a constraint that the ranges be non-overlapping:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (
    during tsrange,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (during WITH &&)
);
```

Comment: any update in last 7 years?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can create a constraint without migration file ( going to the database by consequence ) but as an option, you can use Django fields validations that will raise exceptions in case you validations don't pass

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/